# line following another instance in movieclip

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

i am having trouble making a line to follow another instance(crosshair),my line is not following my crosshair, which cant be because i have set the lineTo to the x and y positions of my crosshair

the swf is here http://megaswf.com/filelinks/1156538 ,

the code where i do the lines are these.

_cross is the cross hair instance, and rodhit is a instance of s symbol that i have put on the "tip" of a fishing rod, therefore i did not include a moveTo.

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, crossLoop);

public function crossLoop(e:Event):void
        {

            //calculations, distance, angle etc
            if (_cross != null)
            {
            var a:Number = _cross.x- x;
            var b:Number = _cross.y - y;
            rodhit.graphics.lineTo(_cross.x, _cross.y);
            var angRad:Number = Math.atan2(b, a);
            var angDeg:Number = (angRad * 180 / Math.PI);
            //trace(angDeg );

            rotation = (angDeg);
            if (angDeg > -10)
                rotation = -10;
            if (angDeg < -170)
                rotation = -170


            }
        }
```

Comment: The SWF you've uploaded does not play for me, it throws an XML error.  Can you describe more clearly the problem you're having, does the line draw in the wrong place or not at all?

Answer (score 1):

here is an example how you could do this: http://wonderfl.net/c/6K52

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Shape;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    public class FlashTest extends Sprite {
        private var _cross:Sprite;
        private var _line:Shape;
        public function FlashTest() {
            _cross = new Sprite();
            _cross.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000, 1);
            _cross.graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, 20);
            addChild(_cross);

            _line = new Shape();
            _line.x = 200;
            _line.y = 30;
            addChild(_line);

            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, onMouseMove);
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);
        }

        private function onMouseMove(evt:MouseEvent):void
        {
            _cross.x = stage.mouseX;
            _cross.y = stage.mouseY;
        }

        private function onEnterFrame(evt:Event):void
        {
            _line.graphics.clear();
            _line.graphics.lineStyle(2, 0x000000, 1);
            _line.graphics.lineTo(_cross.x - _line.x, _cross.y - _line.y);
        }
    }
}
```